# Google sheets : CreateMenu -> addItem refer to function in another script file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create custom menu in Google sheets using Google app script.

I found the following code from google documentation and it is working fine

```html
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
          .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
      .addToUi();
}
```

Now what I want is to have function name menuItem1 to be in a different gs file. The reason I want to do this to organize different category of code into different gs file and for easier maintenance.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is, just put the function name in your `addItem()` like you would if the function was in the same .gs file. Have you even tried it?

Comment: @ross thank you. it worked. I was trying gsfilename.functionname(). I didn't know it was this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in the Script Editor to Edit->Current Project’s Triggers, you can manually add a new Trigger

[image]

and link it to the function you want to run. You can choose the function from any .gs file within the project you want. However, you should be aware that a project can contain several .gs files, but you can call any function within your project just by name - no matter in which .gs file it is defined. Thus, it is very important to give all your functions within a project different names to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: thank you. I got it now. I thought I have to include the gs name when calling a function not in current file